# Git pull from specific branch

Tags: git, pull

I want to pull changes from specified branch to my local repository, but I don't wont it to merge with master branch. What is the right way to do that?  Do I have to make my own branch and than pull?

Comment: This is what `git fetch` is for.

Comment: I think you may be muddling terminology: "pull" in git means "fetch + merge". Where do you want the changes to show up? In your working copy so you can view them? In a graph view?

Comment: @IMSoP In my working copy

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`git pull` is the same as `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.

To create a local branch tracking a branch on a remote, first fetch from the remote and then run `git checkout` with the name of a branch that matches that on the remote:

```
git fetch <remote>
git checkout <branch>
```

- `<remote>` is the name of the remote, for instance `origin`.
- `<branch>` is the name of a branch on that remote. If `git branch -r` shows a branch name `origin/foo`, Git should set this up correctly if you do `git checkout foo`.